# Peewee fn.AVG() returns int, expected float

Tags: sql, peewee

For some reason peewee `fn.AVG()` function returns `int` values, while it is supposed to return `float`.

If I execute the following raw SQL query in DB Browser:

```
SELECT players.name, AVG(marks.skill) FROM players 
JOIN marks ON player_id = players.id 
GROUP BY players.id;
```

I get the correct result:

```
Charname | 6.6
```

However, if I execute this Python code:

```
from peewee import *
import models

query = (
    models.Player.select(
        models.Player.name,
        fn.AVG(models.Mark.skill).alias('skill'),
    )
    .join(models.Mark, JOIN.LEFT_OUTER)
    .group_by(models.Player.id)
)

for q in query:
    print(q.name, q.skill, type(q.skill))
```

I get the result as truncated `int`:

```
Charname 6 int
```

What might be wrong?

I'm using SQLite, `models.Mark.skill` is an `IntegerField`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to chain `.coerce(False)` to the `fn.AVG()` - this tells Peewee that we don't want to treat the resulting aggregate as an integer (since this func is called with a single argument corresponding to an integer field):

```
query = (
    models.Player.select(
        models.Player.name,
        fn.AVG(models.Mark.skill).coerce(False).alias('skill'),
    )
    .join(models.Mark, JOIN.LEFT_OUTER)
    .group_by(models.Player.id)
)
```

Doc: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Function.coerce

Comment: Thank you very much! Both for the answer and for peewee, I absolutely love it :)